Cannot find module 'firebase/app' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
I'm trying to import initializeApp from firebase/app with
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"

and I'm getting the error

Cannot find module 'firebase/app' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

I have tried uninstalling/reinstalling firebase. And tried removing the project-lock.json file and node_modules and running npm install again.
tsconfig.js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2017",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}

package.json
{
  "name": "yt-web-client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@grpc/grpc-js": "^1.12.4",
    "firebase": "^11.0.2",
    "next": "15.0.4",
    "react": "^19.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^19.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^19",
    "@types/react-dom": "^19",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "15.0.4",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}



set the module resolution to node
"moduleResolution": "node"

and use
npm install @types/firebase --save-dev

before this delete node modules, package lock file
